# PDF.JS Change Page section

Tags: javascript, firefox, pdf

I want to customize the behaviour of previous and next buttons inside the PDF.JS Viewer. I've found that inside viewer.js there is:

```
document.getElementById('previous').addEventListener('click',
  function() {
    PDFView.page--;
});
document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click',
  function() {
    PDFView.page++;
});
```

For example I would like that, by clicking on the next button, does not change the page but just scroll down about 10 lines.

I hope that someone could help me.

Thanks

-Antonio

Answer (score 0):

You have made half your way to the destination.
However, you need to check the

```
scrollIntoView = function pageViewScrollIntoView(dest){...}
```

the PDFView.page is responsible for the page, 
the `scrollIntoView` is responsible for the offset, which in this case what you are looking for.

Comment: This doesn't seem to do the trick neither - I just tried with: `pdfViewer.currentPageNumber = p; pdfViewer.scrollPageIntoView(p);` but it's not enough... I also tried `pdfLinkService.page++;` but that doesn't work either... neither does any other combination... any more ideas?

Comment: this has been there for ages, I dont know if it still really works. but you can try here maybe it still and it will show you how to use it
https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=scrollIntoview